# download_to_filename hangs if network disconnects in the middle

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

I have an issue where I am downloading large files from Google Cloud Storage and if the network disconnects in the middle of a download the download_to_filename method just hangs. I have not been able to find a way to set a timeout on it to prevent it from just causing my entire program to hang. Is there a way to force it to timeout or am I missing something?

```
from google.cloud import storage

client = storage.Client('project-id')
bucket = client.get_bucket('bucket-name')
blob = storage.blob.Blob('Large-file.txt', bucket)
blob.download_to_filename(blob.name)
```

This only seems to happen if I disconnect from the network in the middle of the download_to_filename method. If I disconnect prior to the download_to_filename, then I get a ConnectionError.

I can handle any exceptions raised, I just cannot have this hanging.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to create a "session" object, with a defined timeout and then use it to create the the storage.Client. In [1] and [2] you will find the definition for the object "storage.Client" and "request".

This info may be helpful to understand how the timeout works [3].

1. https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/client.html
2. http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Session.request
3. http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#timeouts

Comment: If I understand this correctly, the requests session does not have a timeout. Just the `session.request(...)` can be given a timeout. But the storage client takes a session not a request. How can I set the timeout on a session?

Answer (score 0):

download_to_filename() has a timeout parameter.

```
blob.download_to_filename(filename, timeout=n_seconds)
```

Comment: Just noticed this parameter may not have existed back when you posted this, it's not in early versions of the library.